# How to get access XML file from Javascript (two ways and every thing bug )

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

--- I try everything on internet and nothing work (Only vanilla CSS + XML + XSL) ---

I am try to get access XML value from javaScript but it doesn't work

First time I try to do it
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
```

And have error on that - xhttp.open("GET", filename, false); line.
Another way I am try do from this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gON4MUdJE8` with Loading XML Data Using Fetch, and he tell me SCRIPT1002: Syntax error on first line for example `fetch('./Albums.xml').then(() => 2)`

I share some code I hope you can help me fix that issue, only try to get value on javascript.

ok my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>
<xmlTag>
blah blah blah
</xmlTag>
```

My XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding ="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/xmlTag">

        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
        </head>
        <html>
            <body id="id">
                 // some code
            </body>
        </html>

        <script src="./javaScript.js"></script> // link to my js file

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Js file

```
fetch('./Albums.xml').then(() => 2)
```

I need to change js file or approach (The connection between files)?
How can I get xml values from Js ?

Thanks guys really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function below will get the `./Albums.xml` file, parse it and return it as an `XMLDocument`. It uses the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to turn a string of XML into an actual XML document which you can use in JavaScript.

```
const getXML = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    resolve(xhr.responseText)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    reject(new TypeError('Request failed'));
  }
  xhr.open('GET', file);
  xhr.send(null);
});

const parseXML = xmlString => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
  return xml;
};

getXML('./Albums.xml').then(xmlString => {
  const xml = parseXML(xmlString);
  console.log(xml);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Your XSLT file has an faulty order in the HTML part. See that the `<head>` is outside of the `<html>` tag here below?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<html>
  <body id="id">
    <!-- Some code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

That should be inside of the ` tag, otherwise it won't work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body id="id">
    <!-- Some code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Some advice for in the future. Steer clear from W3Schools regarding old subjects like the one you presented. The code you've just shown us is ancient and should not be used in this day and age.

Comment: I update HTML tag like you said and add to Javascript.js your code it say - SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
javaScript.js (1,30)

Comment: It can be problem because I am running it on IE? , if yes how can I check it live

Comment: That can certainly be the issue. What version of IE are you using? The JavaScript it suggested won't work any version of IE. Tell us more.

Comment: I am using IE 11 (it only run my XML file with XSL + CSS file etc.. ). I am try anything to allow security cors from chrome, IE Edge and firefox and don't let me any charts only IE 11 (basic on Win10)

Comment: I run it now from chrome and it do that problem / 'javaScript.js:3 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/name/gitStudio/AngularRepo/Temps/Albums/Albums.xml. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
getXML @ javaScript.js:3
(anonymous) @ javaScript.js:10
javaScript.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getXML (javaScript.js:3)
    at javaScript.js:10
getXML @ javaScript.js:3
(anonymous) @ javaScript.js:10
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ javaScript.js:10'

Comment: Okay, so the Fetch API can't use the `file` protocol. For that we have to use the older `XMLHttpRequest`. I've modified the answer to accomodate this. However, you're trying to get a static file from your computer, which will work as long the site runs on your  own computer, not when it runs on a server.

Comment: Thank it really work with that const xml = parseXML(xmlString).documentElement; Now can I change my XML from JS and change on XSL?

Comment: Sure mate, be sure to look up documentation on the `XMLDocument` to see what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure, what you are looking for. I tried the Tutorial and it worked.

```js
// const xmlUrl = '/whatever.xml';
const xmlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
`]));

// const xlsUrl = '/whatever.xsl';
const xslUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
`]));

function http_request(method, url, content, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4 || xhr.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }
        if (!!callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(xhr);
        }
    });
    xhr.send(content);
}

http_request('GET', xmlUrl, void 0, function (xml) {
    const xmlObject = xml.responseXML;
    http_request('GET', xslUrl, void 0, function (xsl) {
        const xslObject = xsl.responseXML;
        const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslObject);
        const resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlObject, document);
        document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```